# oracle 11XE and ODT32 on windows - multiple issues

Tags: windows, oracle

I installed Oracle 11 XE  on a 64bit Windows 2008R2. This is a development machine, therefore I have also installed Oracle Developer Tools for .NET (32bit). Both these installations come with their own version of SQLplus.

I have set up the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora to be identical for both these oracle products, but I cannot connect to the local XE from either SQLplus. I get `ORA-12560` everytime. the Oracle 11 XE home page also doesn't start.

```
   ---TNSNAmes.ora ----
    XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DDSAP236.asxdev.asx.com.au)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

    EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

    ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 
    ----END TNSNAMEs.ora---

---Listener.Ora ---
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Oracle\11Express\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Oracle\11Express\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DMACHINE.MyDomain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)


--End listener.ora----
```

In `services.msc` and `lsntctrl` both shows the `XElistener` service have started.

I am wondering what else I can check?

1. Can I run XE (32bit) on Win2008R2?
2. Can I run XE together with ODTODAC32 on Win2008R2?
3. How do I resolve ORA-12560 so I can connect to the XE database?

### Additional Info

In the registry of this machine under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Note\Oracle` I have 5 folders - can someone confirm if this is correct?
The folders are:

1. `KEY_`  (not sure if this is correct)
2. `KEY_OracleClient11g_HOME` (the Oracle ODT client install's home)
3. `KEY_EX` (11g EX install's home)
4. `ODP.Net` (part of ODP install )
5. `OracleMTSRecoveryService` (part of ODP install)

Comment: Can't guarantee this'll help, but see [this link](http://www.oraclefaq.net/2007/10/15/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adapter-error/).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If that's indeed your TNSNAMES.ORA, your syntax is broken - you have extra spaces in front of the connection aliases (first line of each entry), which might cause your problems. Your TNSNAMES.ORA should look like this:

```
  XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DDSAP236.asxdev.asx.com.au)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

If your "real" TNSNAMES.ORA is correct, however:

- what is the output of lsnrctl status?
- what does your listener log contain?
- does sqlplus / as sysdba work?